# How to go instruction by instruction shown by disassembler in a core in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, disassembly

I am trying to analyze a core dump. There is very little stack frame on the core, so I am using disassembler. Now the disassembler gave a list of instruction in assembly. Now I want to check what is the value of a particular register . As the same register is used multiple number of times I think the value I am trying to access is the last present value. So, is there a way that I can go to particular instruction and then check the register value?

## Example:

```
gdb binary core
disas /s fucntion_name
   0x00007fbb3cc51a9c <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00007fbb3cc51a9d <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00007fbb3cc51aa0:  sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x00007fbb3cc51aa4:  mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00007fbb3cc51aa8:  cmpq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00007fbb3cc51aad:  je     0x7fbb3cc51b0b
   0x00007fbb3cc51aaf:  mov    0x2030c3(%rip),%eax 
   0x00007fbb3cc51ab5:  test   %eax,%eax
   0x00007fbb3cc51ab7:  je     0x7fbb3cc51b0b
   0x00007fbb3cc51ab9:  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdi
   0x00007fbb3cc51abd:  callq  0x7fbb3caf8df0 
   0x00007fbb3cc51ac2:  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007fbb3cc51ac6:  mov    0x28(%rax),%eax
   0x00007fbb3cc51ac9:  lea    -0x1(%rax),%edx
   0x00007fbb3cc51acc:  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007fbb3cc51ad0:  mov    %edx,0x28(%rax)
   0x00007fbb3cc51ad3:  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007fbb3cc51ad7:  mov    0x28(%rax),%eax
   0x00007fbb3cc51ada:  test   %eax,%eax
   0x00007fbb3cc51adc:  jne    0x7fbb3cc51b02
   0x00007fbb3cc51ade:  mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007fbb3cc51ae2:  mov    0x2c(%rax),%eax
```

Now, suppose I want to check the value of register "rbp" at instruction whose address is `0x00007fbb3cc51ac2`; how can I check?  I can't run the program, as it is just a core file from the customer.

Comment: You can't see previous register value in same frame (at least in core dump), but with my rudimentary knowledge of x86-64 assembly I can't see any instruction that changes rbp after beginning of the function. You can see value of rbp in previous frame by doing "up" and examining value there.

Answer (score 1):

> As the same register is used multiple number of times I think the value I am trying to access is the last present value.

Using the register doesn't alter its value, only writing to it does.

If the register is written to multiple times, then yes: you will see in the core dump the last value written to it.

> So, is there a way that I can go to particular instruction and then check the register value?

What you are asking for is effectively [reverse debugging](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ReverseDebug). While it can be done, it carries a very significant overhead (in both memory and execution speed). A "normal" core dump certainly doesn't have the info to perform reverse debugging.

> I want to check the value of register "rbp" at instruction whose address is 0x00007fbb3cc51ac2; how can I check?

That's relatively easy: since `%rbp` is only stored to once (instruction at `0x7fbb3cc51a9d`) the value should be the same as it is at any other location in the function.

Note: this assumes that every function you called saved and restored the value of `%rbp` (which is required by the ABI). It is possible that one of the routines is buggy and didn't correctly restore the value, in which case you are mostly screwed. However, you should also be able to restore the value of `%rbp` from `%rsp`: they were equal after `0x7fbb3cc51a9d`, and then `%rsp` was decremented by `0x10` at `0x7fbb3cc51aa0`. So it must be that `%rbp == %rsp + 0x10`.